# Difference between the cone and open cone

Tags: general-topology

What is the difference between the cone 
$$CX=X\times [0,1]/X\times \{0\}$$ and the open cone
$$OC(X)=X\times [0,1)/X\times \{0\}?$$
I mean what is done by taking $[0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is. You could as well ask what is the difference between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$, which are just $C(\ast)$ and $OC(\ast)$. They are different spaces, $[0,1]$ is compact while $[0,1)$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

In the open cone we don't have the extra $X \times \{1\}$ that appears in the normal cone (note this end is not the end that is quotiented out).

For example if you take $CS^1$, the cone of the circle, you get a space homeomorphic to the closed disk (it includes the outer circle). However if we take $OC(S^1)$ we don't have this outer circle and the space is homeomorphic to the open disk as we do not have $S^1 \times \{1\}$ any more.

Comment: In particular, $CS^1$ is compact while $OC(S^1)$ is not!

Comment: So basically, $OC(X)=C(X)-X$ and having to dinstinguish both constructions is for compacity reasons.

Comment: @palio: One could add that the open cone $OC(X)$ is a subspace of $C(X)$. This follows since the quotient map $X\times I\to C(X)$ restricts to a quotient map $X\times[0,1)\to OC(X)$. That's because the space $X\times[0,1)$ contains all the points that are identified in any way.